# Google Chrome Javascript Debugger: pause on exception and print exception?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript-debugger

I'm aware of the functionality within Google Chrome's Dev Tools to pause on exceptions however I wish the console to log the exception prior to pausing. At the moment, I've set the browser to pause prior to excecuting an Unhandled Exception but I desire it to print the exception prior to pausing instead of me having to work out from the line reference what caused the exception.